# libpq.so not in `pg_config --libdir` path [OpenSUSE]

Tags: postgresql, opensuse, zypper

As the title says, the library `libpq.so` is not in the path given by `pg_config --libdir`. I install `postgresql posqtgresql-devel` which provides the package `libpq5` which in turn installs the `libpq.so`.

```
    $ pg_config --libdir
    /usr/lib/postgresql10/lib64
    $ find /usr/ -name libpq.so
    /usr/lib64/libpq.so
```

Our applications rely on the path given by `pg_config --libdir` to look for `libpq.so` but it fails. Is this some problem with OpenSUSE package management or is it that we shouldn't be using `pg_config` for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_config` provides information about how PostgreSQL was built.

It is usually used to build server extensions, but it should also work with client code like you are trying to do.

Since your PostgreSQL is installed in a path that contains the version, but your `libpq.so` is not, I'd assume that the latter is a symbolic link rather than being part of the installation package.

If there is no `libpq.so` in your PostgreSQL `lib` directory, I'd call that a packaging error. You should discuss that with the packagers.

Comment: thx! guess I can simlink `pgsql.so` to the `pg_config --libdir` path right? it's not done automatically in my opensuse installation, but idk if that's the norm

Comment: I'd rather add `/usr/lib64` to `LDFLAGS` when building software. It is a fairly standard directory.